# Open Camera in Video Mode

Tags: iphone

In my application, I want to open the camera in Video mode. So I write the following code:

```
myImagePickerController.mediaTypes =  [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
```

And include

```
#import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>
```

But it shows the following errors:

> "_kUTTypeMovie", referenced from:
>       _kUTTypeMovie$non_lazy_ptr in CameraActionViewfor3_0Controller.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Please let me know why it is showing such kind of errors.

Is it for the absence of a framework or it is for something else?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you linked the correct Frameworks?

Comment: The framework you probably want is the MobileCoreServices.framework (from http://twitter.com/fraserspeirs/statuses/2241757169)